# "had + past participle " VS "could have + past participle " in conditional sentence

Tags: modal-verbs, present-perfect, conditional-constructions

The following sentence is collected from cricinfo.com:

> They were under a little bit of pressure then. *If we could have carried on,* we could have set them 220 or even more than that. So to get out then was very disappointing.

I wonder why the writer has used "could have + carried on " instead of "had + carried on".  What does the writer want to express?

Comment: Because the writer is discussing the possibility; using had carried on gets rid of the phrasing **as possibility**. Modals make all the difference in English.

Answer (score 0):

The writer wants to express:

*We wanted to carry on, but it was not possible.*

If they had simply written *If we had carried on ...* it would have expressed only that they did not do so.

---

In this context, *could* + not + *have* + [past participle] is used to say that something was not possible, or that it didn't happen (was not "real", actualized, or manifested). The *not* is implied in the conditional formation.

"There is no past tense, but *could have* followed by a past participle is used for referring to something in the past that was not real, or something that may possibly have been real:
*I could have been killed.*
*What was that noise? Could it have been the wind?*"

-- https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/could

Answer (score -1):

"Could have carried on" is simply inexact English.  Your instinct is correct:  "If we had carried on, we could have set them..." would have been a much better construction.